# Extract part of the string based on delimiters

Tags: c#

I need help to develop a logic that will extract part of the string when the user enter a "delimiter"

For example:

```
string data = "|cBlue|pDaisy|pRose|mTomato|mWheat|pCabbage|p100 units|d19.0";
string userInput = //User enter input
```

So, if the user enters "|c", it should return "Blue"

If the user enters "|m", it should return "Tomato", "Wheat" as 2 strings.

If the user enters "|p", it should return "Daisy", "Rose", "Cabbage" and "100 units" as 4 different strings.

If the user enters something that is not exist, say for example, |z, it will return nothing or an empty string "".

Note: This is just a sample data, the actual data consists of |a - |z, |A - |Z

Comment: What have you attempted yourself in trying to solve this problem, and what issues are you having with your implementation?

Comment: What idf the user enters ":x"? Why is the first result not "Blue|pDaisy|p..." ? In other words, how hard-coded is the "|" and then why does the user have to enter it?

Answer (score 2):

Start with [string.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to tokenize the string.

Then iterate over each token. Pull out its first character and construct a `Dictionary<char, string>` using the first character as a key and the remainder as a value.

Then simply do a dictionary lookup on the desired character to find the relevant token.

Comment: I have tried similar approach but it will not work. When you use .Split, it will remove the delimiter itself. So in this case, say the user enter "|c", the end result will be just "Blue", so if you search for the first char, it will be "B" but not "c"

Comment: @C.J. So put the `|` back on each token. Or remove it from the user's input before you do your dictionary lookup. Be creative... as a programmer you will have to use some basic creative problem-solving skills to handle situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

First get the input,parse it.Use `Split` method then filter the `words` by first letter,Something like this:

```
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

if(userInput.Length == 2)
{
    var words = data.Split(userInput[0]).Where(x => x.StartsWith(userInput[1].ToString()));

    if(words.Any())
    {
       var result = words.Select(x => x.Substring(1)).ToList();
    }
    else 
    {
       // no word found
    }
}
```